# .NEW MVC ignores the size of the popup window when a parameter passed and opens in a new Tab

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a button in the View and PopUp function is processed when it is clicked.
When I remove the parameter from the Action in the Controller, button opens the page as a popup window as intended. However, when I introduce an argument in the Action in the controller, it completely ignores the height, width etc. of the page and opens it in a new tab. Any help will be appreciated.

Button and JS Code.

```js
<script>
    function popup(url, title) {

        var popupWindow = window.open(url, title,  'scrollbars=1,height=500,width=500, top=150, left=300');

    }
</script>
```

```html
<td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="popup('@Url.Action("NewStudentSchedule","Admin", new{ id=id})','New Student Schedule')">Schedule</button></td>
```

Action in the controlller.

```
   public ActionResult NewStudentSchedule(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try removing the ">" before Schedule in your html button**

```
<td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="popup('@Url.Action("NewStudentSchedule","Admin", new{ id=id})','New Student Schedule')"**>**Schedule</button></td>
```